# aggegrate in mongoose for unqiue and recent values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to fetch recent data from a list without duplicates in mongoose.

Data set:

```
{"_id":"3214242", "name": "google", "created":"20200411", "value": 23}
{"_id":"3214243", "name": "google", "created":"20200410", "value": 21}
{"_id":"3214244", "name": "microsoft", "created":"20200409", "value": 25}
{"_id":"3214245", "name": "apple", "created":"20200411", "value": 23}
{"_id":"3214246", "name": "microsoft", "created":"20200411", "value": 30}
```

I want to fetch as unqiue names with last created.
Sample output expected:

```
{"_id":"3214242", "name": "google", "created":"20200411", "value": 23}
{"_id":"3214245", "name": "apple", "created":"20200411", "value": 23}
{"_id":"3214246", "name": "microsoft", "created":"20200411", "value": 30}
```

I tried with group and aggregates. But didnt work

```
db.aggregate(["$group": {"_id": {"name": $name, "value": "$value"}}, { "created": { "$max": "$created" }}])
```

For some reason this doesnt seem to work. I get all the results. Can someone suggest? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [$sort](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) by `created` field and then run [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) to get `value` and `_id` from the field with highest `created` for each `name`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $sort: { created: -1 } },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$name",
            __id: { $first: "$_id" },
            created: { $first: "$created" },
            value: { $first: "$value" },
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: "$__id",
            name: "$_id",
            created: 1,
            value: 1
        }
    }  
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1RC4KSdd9nq)